# The primary reference could not be resolved because it was built against a higher version than the currently targeted framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, restsharp

First of all: I have knowledge regarding the immediate solution to the problem in the title.

I know that this problem arises whenever a dll is referenced under a project being built against a different framework.

I have a project being built against .NET Framework 4.0, and I am referencing the RestSharp dll that targets the same framework.

The print below has been taken from JetBrain's DotPeek.
[image: Printscreen]

Dunno if this print means anything at all, but nonetheless.
[image: Vs2010 printscreen]

The error being displayed at the Output Window is

```
The primary reference "RestSharp" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".
```

I am using VS2010.

Comment: Downvoters: Please provide a comment as to why this question could/should be redacted.

Comment: I also have the same issue but with different package.

Answer (score 1):

You are having that problem because that version of the dll was built using .net framework 4.6.

What you can do to fix it is one of the following:

1. Find that dll built with .net framework 4.0
2. Clone the repository and build it yourself pointing to .net framework 4.0
3. Change your project to target .net framework 4.6